# What are the minimum cell phone specs needed to work in UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, telephone, telecommunications

I am planning on buying a cell phone soon in the US. Preferably, I would want a phone that has dual SIM card slots and quad frequency capability (850/900/1,800/1,900 MHz). Is this all I need hardware-wise for a phone to work in the UK (and possibly Europe in general)?

Other than that, I would need the appropriate phone plan. Are there more requirements I need? Such as: do the WiFi bands in the US work with WiFi in the UK (that phones use, laptops, etc.)?

Comment: Are you after a 3g or a 4g phone? (Bands used often differ)

Comment: The bands you list are 2G GSM bands. Those aren't a particularly important consideration any more, partly because it is hard to find phones that don't support them these days but mostly because no one wants to actually use 2G GSM any more. It is the 3G and LTE/4G band support that matters more.

Comment: I wonder if this question might not be better suited for the Travel SE?

Comment: Definitely does not belong in Expats

Comment: @Dennis do you know which frequencies are the 4G/LTE bands?

Comment: @ouflak and Scott Earle, I debated whether I should put this under Travel. I figured a long-term stay needed a long-term solution, not a short-term solution (like renting an international phone).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WiFi should not be a problem.

The only thing to watch for is that your phone needs to be GSM not CDMA, and needs to support at least the 900MHz and 1800MHz bands.

The phone's manufacturer should have a website listing compatibility across carriers around the world. Example: [here is Apple's page listing iPhone compatibility with LTE bands around the world](https://www.apple.com/iphone/LTE/).